# Why is Minix not "saving" '.o' files when I rebuild using 'make services'/'make install' (and last modification date in the future)?

Tags: c, build, minix

I'm having some trouble with Minix. Whenever I navigate to /usr/src/releasetools and do 'make services' then 'make install', it appears as if the program doesn't update. So for example, when I go to /usr/src/servers/pm and modify my C file 'do_something.c', the C file saves fine. But when I go to 'make' it in Minix, it appears as though the file 'do_something.o' doesn't update. In fact, sometimes the last modification time is in the future.

I've found a temporary workaround by deleting the '.o' file whenever I rebuild, but it's a bit of a hassle. Can anyone help?